# Zlib.Gunzip not working in Grafana Plugin

Tags: reactjs, plugins, grafana, zlib

I am creating my first Grafana panel plugin to display GLG grphics. I am using react simple panel plugin.
For GLG implementation I am having GLG static library(can't install with npm). So I added my GLG library files(GlgCE.js, GlgTooklitCE.js, gunzip.min.js) in external folder. I am importing all these library files in SimplePanel.tsx file. One of my step is to decompress created the data.In my GlgToolkit.js I am having below code which creates object for Zlib.Gunzip and decompress the data which is in Uint8Array format.

```
tproto.__glg_gunzip_hook__ = (data) => {
var gunzip = new Zlib.Gunzip(data);
return gunzip.decompress();
```

};

My problem is that above code is not working, while debugging I can say its unable to create object for Zlib.Gunzip. It returing undefine for gunzip variable, and data is not getting decompress.
I will be great if anybody caan help me on this.How can one library file can communicate with other(in this case gunzip.min.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution, I imported the gunzip.min.js file in my library file.
import * as Zlib from './gunzip.min.js';